# How do I get rid of the tags in XPath

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xquery

I have a bunch of html files with tons of data in it and I want to extract the important parts of it.

The files are all very similar; I've to search for a `<tr>` which contains a certain keyword. The third column of this table row always contains the name of the "block" I'm searching for (it's a few table rows).

```
//body/table/tbody/tr[td = "Deployed to"]/td[3]/div//span[text()]
```

with this XPath query I get the names (maybe one, maybe more)
The problem is, how do I get rid of the tags around the data?

Right now my output is something like this:

```
<span class="log_entry_text">Name1</span><span class="log_entry_text">Name2</span><span class="log_entry_text">Name3</span>
```

I want to have something like that: Name1 Name2 Name3
So I can use it for extracting these blocks more easily.
With string() i can only extract the first element (result would be: Name1)

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your xpath with data() element like data(//body/table/tbody/tr[td = "Deployed to"]/td[3]/div//span[text()]) for retrieve text.

Comment: thy for your help; I took your former answer: //body/table/tbody/tr[td = "Deployed to"]/td[3]/div//span/text() and it worked perfectly well for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression asks to retrieve `span` elements and that's what it has returned. If you're seeing tags with angle brackets in the output, that's because of the way the XPath result is being processed and rendered by the receiving application.

If you're in XPath 2.0+ or XQuery 1.0+ you can combine the several span elements into a single string using

```
string-join(//path/span, ' ')
```